# Is 'to sustain to' idiomatic in 'X sustains a relation to Y?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vi8uAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22sustains%20to%22&pg=PA161#v=onepage&q=%22sustains%20to%22&f=false) p 161, What is Reality?, by Francis Howe Johnson [BA (Harvard, 1856)](https://books.google.com/books?id=DsKvAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1245&ots=mmaROpkCXI&dq=%22Francis%20Howe%20Johnson%22%20harvard&pg=PA1245#v=onepage&q=%22Francis%20Howe%20Johnson%22%20harvard&f=false)

> The relations which the *ego* 
>   sustains to the living tissues of the body and to its 
>   various organs and faculties seem to have very little 
>   in common with the relations that it **sustains to** 
>   other intelligent beings; [...]
>   If, therefore, we attach ourselves to the first for 
>   a conception of the relations that the Supreme Be-ing **sustains to** the universe, does not this choice 
>   absolutely exclude the use of the other two sets of 
>   relations, which we must regard as equally real ?

This use is exemplified [in modern (very formal) usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22sustains+to%22#q=%22sustains+to%22&hl=en&tbm=bks&start=10). I know that the (Latin) verb 'sustain' here means ['to bear, support'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=support&searchmode=none), but it sounds wrong to write:

> X (bear/supports/)sustains a relation TO Y. = X sustains TO Y a relation.

The preposition 'with' would be used instead of 'to'. So is the use of 'to' correct?
Excluding rarity and esotericism in usage, what might explain and naturalise this use?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=relation+to%2C+relation+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crelation%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crelation%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You can use ngram to decide whether you are going to have to accustom yourself to a usage. This particular odd duck is in the hands of the taxidermist: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sustains+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csustains%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "sustains" with one of its synonyms.  What would you get?  I get (by using "keeps"):

> "... to have very little in common with the relations that it ***keeps*** to other intelligent beings;

Is it now easier to understand?

The preposition "to" is related to "relations", not to the verb.

It is possible to say "*relations **with***" or "*relations **toward***" instead of "*relations **to***", the difference is not so significant.  Curiously enough, Google gives fewer results for "relations *to* other" than for "relations *with* other" (with quotes).  So, 'with' is a more common preposition, I reckon.

---

I do not think that "*relation **to***" is somehow rare or esoteric.  The verb '*relate*' when used with a preposition, mostly employs '***to***' (rather than '***with***'), so "relation *to*" has just as much right to exist in our everyday language as "relation *with*", I think.

Comment: +1. Thanks. My last question: I meant to ask what might explain and accustom me to this use, besides considering this use rare and esoteric (which don't deepen my comprehension). Better?

Answer (score 1):

The verb is irrelevant. *Relation* has taken complementary preposition phrases headed with *to* for almost 600 years.

> **1433** *Rolls of Parlt.* IV.451/2 Yat yis saide worde Cloth..have relation and understondyng to hole Clothes..and not to other Clothes.
>    —cited in *OED 1*, *s.v.* **Relation**, 4.a.

You have access to the online *OED*, which may have even remoter instances.

*Relationship*, *relate*, and *relative* likewise take complements with *to*.